# Need to print string only once in a for loop - simple beginner banking program

Tags: java

New to programming. I have to make a simple banking program. It works fine if I exceed or stay within the balance. If I withdraw exactly the amount left it will still work and print the remaining amounts that couldn't be taken out but the line "The following loan requests could not be facilitated." won't be printed.

If I put that line in the last end if statement within the loop it will repeat multiple times for the number of times there's a loan left, I need it to appear only once. Stooped, been at it a few hours now and can't figure out a solution. It works 95% overall. The end has to look like below. Appreciate any help

[image of end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTusU.png)

```
public class Exercise2 {

public static void main (String[] args) {

    int loanRequests[] = {80,20,100,300,50,65,100,15};
    int balance = 500;
    String pot = "Cash in the pot: ";
    String request = "Loan amount requested: ";


    for (int i = 0; i < loanRequests.length; i++) {
        if (balance >= loanRequests[i])  {
            System.out.println(pot + balance);               
            System.out.println(request + loanRequests[i] + " - Loan amount granted! " +  "\n");
            balance = (balance - loanRequests[i]);
       }else if (balance < loanRequests[i] && balance > 0) {
           System.out.println(pot + balance + "\n" + request + loanRequests[i]);
           System.out.println("The exact loan amount cannot be processed in full (insufficent funds available).");
           System.out.println("However we will give you what we can... " + balance);
           System.out.println("\n"+ pot + (balance - balance) + "\n" +  "\n" + "The following amounts could not be facilitated");
           balance = 0;
       }else 
          System.out.println(loanRequests[i]);

        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Hi man I am not sure If i understood what you meant. But I will provide what I think is answer for your problem. This will print your "The following loan requests could not be facilitated." only once.

```
public class Exercise2 {

  static String getRestLoanRequestsString(int index,int requests[]){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); //good practice to use StringBuilder when concating strings in loop
    builder.append("The following loan requests could not be facilitated:\n");
    for(; index < requests.length;index++){
        builder.append(requests[index])
                .append("\n");
    }
    return builder.toString();
  }

public static void main (String[] args) {

    int loanRequests[] = {80,20,100,300,50,65,100,15};
    int balance = 500;
    String pot = "Cash in the pot: ";
    String request = "Loan amount requested: ";


    for (int i = 0; i < loanRequests.length; i++) {
        if (balance >= loanRequests[i])  {
            System.out.println(pot + balance);               
            System.out.println(request + loanRequests[i] + " - Loan amount granted! " +  "\n");
            balance = (balance - loanRequests[i]);
       }else if (balance < loanRequests[i] && balance > 0) {
           System.out.println(pot + balance + "\n" + request + loanRequests[i]);
           System.out.println("The exact loan amount cannot be processed in full (insufficent funds available).");
           System.out.println("However we will give you what we can... " + balance);
           System.out.println("\n"+ pot + (balance - balance) + "\n" +  "\n" + "The following amounts could not be facilitated");
           balance = 0;
        }else {
          System.out.println(getRestLoanRequestsString(i,loanRequests));
          break; //break the for loop because we don't have funds to give more loans
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: hey i really appreciate your effort.. it works perfectly. sadly its a bit too advanced for what my tutor is expecting, we've only done very basic stuff so the new stuff you added is double dutch to me :-) - thanks alot ill try to decipher and learn from  it

Comment: @javanoob123 you could get rid of the "getRestLoanRequestsString" method and just take the method code and paste it into else statement If you want I can edit It :)